# How do I move h1 text to the bottom of box?

Tags: html, css

I want to move the h1 text (You say tag ) to the bottom, however I could not do it.
Sorry , pardon for asking such a simple question but I need help as it is my 1st day !

So far I
Thank you !

[here is the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0wTL.png)

This was the mistake I made, before asking here. I tried to use CSS to align them by the position or align. However, it still didn't worked.
Therefore, the way I solved it was by just putting the h1 (YOU SAY TAG) under the div  .

```
<div class="box1">
  <H1> YOU SAY TAG </H1>
    <div class="box2">
        <h1> WHEN I SAY DIV...</h1></div>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: It sounds like this is an HTML question. If so, it should be tagged with [tag:html] not [tag:visual-studio-code]; your editor of choice shouldn’t be relevant to your question. Also, it’d be useful to hear what you’ve tried. What does your current markup look like? That will make it easier for the community to offer a solution that’s easier to follow, since it will be grounded in a shared baseline everyone is working off of.

Comment: Sure ! I edit them inside. sorry for the wrong tagging .

Comment: No problem. It can take a while to get the hang of Stack Overflow! It’s useful to think of threads more like a wiki than a forum, where we’re striving to help both current and future readers find and understand a problem, as well as any proposed solutions. Given that, thank you for taking the time to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your `<h1>` text *under* the `child` `div` inside your `parent` `div`

```
<style>
    .parent {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    .child {
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 80%;
        height: 200;
    }
</style>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <h1>When I say div... </h1>
    </div>
    <h1>You say tag </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. One of the newest is with flexbox.
Check this page to learn about flexbox: https://flexboxfroggy.com/ it's a cool game designed to teach.